# LDAP: Filter users belonging to a group across multiple OU's

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I've the following structure in AD

```
DC=comp,DC=com
    OU=city1
       OU=group
       OU=users
         user1
         user2
    OU=city2
       OU=group
       OU=users
         user3
         user4
```

I am trying to filter and retrieve user 1-4 in a single query. I've tried the filter
(dn=OU=users,ou=*,DC=comp,DC=com) but it returned empty. What's the best way to filter in this condition?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft Active Directory does not support [extensible match filter](https://ldap.com/ldap-filters/) for this condition.

If these are the only users, setting a base at "DC=comp,DC=com" will return the users.

Comment: Thank you for providing the link.